Will the ratio of the remnant against the condemned during the days of Noah be equal to the equivalent ratio on judgment day?
I have no idea about the exact population of the world that was judged during the time of Noah since they were a couple of generations from Adam but according to archaeological and anthropological perspectives, they were approximately thirty million people.

From an archaeological and anthropological perspective, human populations during this time were still relatively small. Around 3000 BCE, the global population is estimated to have been roughly 20–30 million people, based on studies of early agricultural societies in Mesopotamia, Egypt, the Indus Valley, and China.

If you get the ratio of the saved i.e. Noah's family to the ratio of the men who were doomed to die in the flood, then it is going to be something like:
8:30000000 ~ 1:3750000
which meant that for every one righteous person saved: three million, seven hundred and fifty thousand wicked people received condemnation.
Will that ratio stand on judgment day since the preacher Ecclesiastes speaking under the influence of the Holy Spirit said these golden words regarding the connection between history and the future.
Ecclesiastes 1:9

What has been will be again, what has been done will be done again; there is nothing new under the sun.

Which means that ratio is most likely to be retained even on judgment day because nothing is new under the sun?

Please read What types of questions can I ask on this site?

By simple mathematics, no. The number of people who have ever lived is estimated around 117 billion. Applying your ratio gives us 31,200 saved. But Revelation gives us at least 144,000 that were sealed from Israel alone. We're already 423 billion people short, before we even begin to cover saved people from other nations and times.

@user111403, the 144000 refers to all saints saved from Abraham to Jesus

Even if you intend to argue that there will only be 144,000 people saved total (which I think is a completely indefensible position), we're still hundreds of billions of people short of achieving that ratio.

Short answer:
The conclusion is wrong, because this is a really bad way to read and interpret Bible texts.
Slightly longer answer
The conclusion is wrong because it takes two random passages from unrelated parts of the Bible and joins them together in an arbitrary way. Let me answer the question by asking another question of my own:
Why aren't any of the following verses included in the analysis?

Isaiah 42:9 NIV
See, the former things have taken place, and new things I declare.
Isaiah 43:19
See, I am doing a new thing! Now it springs up; do you not perceive it?

The point here is that Ecclesiastes talks about the repetitive nature of human life. But Isaiah reminds us that God is quite able to do new and different things.

Revelation 7:9 NIV
After this I looked, and there before me was a great multitude that no one could count, from every nation, tribe, people and language, standing before the throne and before the Lamb.

The point here is that in the final analysis we can expect the numbers of those saved to be both large, and uncountable.

Romans 11:33-36 NIV
33 Oh, the depth of the riches of the wisdom and[i] knowledge of God!
How unsearchable his judgments,
and his paths beyond tracing out!
34 “Who has known the mind of the Lord?
Or who has been his counselor?”[j]
35 “Who has ever given to God,
that God should repay them?”[k]
36 For from him and through him and for him are all things.
To him be the glory forever! Amen.

The point here is that God is God, and we are not. Some areas of life must be left to him as outside of our knowledge and responsibility. Surely the precise numbers of those who are to be saved or condemned at the final judgment is one of those areas.
